# Transform a namespace that exports types to a union type of these types

Tags: typescript

I have a file `index.ts` which exports a few types, as follows:

```js
// [...]

export {
    UsalonData,
    TalonData,
    UsageData,
    GateSaclayData,
    EcsData,
    EffacementData,
    SplineData,
    RegressionData,
    CompdivData,
    ClusteringData,
    ClassificationData
};
```

And in another file, I use these types as a generic type:

```js
// [...]

export default interface Study<
    T = UsalonData | TalonData | UsageData | GateSaclayData // | .....
> {
    // ...
}
```

But I would like to create a union type using utility types instead of copying them one by one.

I tried the following:

```js
import * as allStudiesTypes from '../algos-types';
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
type AllDataUnion = Values<typeof allStudiesTypes>;
```

But it resolves to `type AllDataUnion = never`

Comment: Why not just create a union type of them in the `index.ts` and export it?

Comment: If it's just exporting types and not values, then `keyof T` is not going to have anything in it. Where is the "object of types" you speak of, exactly? There are no types in any "object" as far as I can see; I suppose you mean "namespace". If so then this is essentially impossible. I'm almost certain this has been asked/answered before; I'll try to find it

Comment: Yes, I was confusing namespace and objects, because of the similar syntax...